# .NET ClickOnce application. Can resolve de URL or domain of the page from it was launched?

Tags: .net, clickonce

In one side, I have a desktop .NET application, deployed in a virtual directory with ClickOnce. In other side, have a Java EE web application, with a link to the publication URL of the dekstop .NET application.

For example, in page page *http: //mydomain.com/page.jps* we could have a link to *http: //otherdomain.com/apps/mydesktoapp.application*

I would like the .NET desktop app to know the url or domain from where it was called (*http: //mydomain.com/page.jps*)

I know that we can pass parameters to the publication Url, but I'd prefer not to use that.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The application has no way to obtain the refferer page since it's completely independant of the HTTP stream. Wikor's code above will show you the actual URI of the application launched, but not the referrer.

Unless you're hosting the deployment page in a dynamic langage (php, asp, jsp) and customise the deploy page to embed the http referrer and pass it to the application as launch parameter.

```
private NameValueCollection GetQueryStringParameters()
{
    NameValueCollection nameValueTable = new NameValueCollection();

    if (ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed)
    {
        string queryString = ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.ActivationUri.Query;
        nameValueTable = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(queryString);
    }

    return (nameValueTable);
}
```

However you must be aware that it implies that you are fully aware if your applicatoin is run online or offline. In case of offline, you're pretty sure that it will be activated only one time the first time with the url, then launched through the start menu option. Moreover, you must make sure that the application can run without having a query provided or a corrupted one.

Hope that helped

Comment: Thanks @Kharaone!, this answer confirms my initial guess

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed )
{
    string activationUri = System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.ActivationUri;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Wiktor, I tried it, but this property returns the Uri where de desktop app is published, not the Url of the page having the link we use to launch the app.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. There's no way to get the referrer uri from the application unless you pass it in an explicit way in the uri.

Comment: @WiktorZychla is there a way of getting the Uri when it has been run from the desktop / start menu as well? Regards

Comment: @Jon: I don't know unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks anyway, been googling for a while and came across this thread, so thought I would take a chance.  All the best.